# How do you share code between two VSTS build tasks?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I need to share some TypeScript classes between two VSTS build tasks. As I understand, all compiled files required to be in the task folder to be able to function the build task.

Current scenario:
I have common files in common folder in the root folder of the VSTS code base. I have two task A and B which utilize these classes. When I package the code it ignores the common folder.

Is it possible to achieve this in above scenario? Please advice.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be achieved. Each build task are independent of each other. You may have to add the classes for both task respectively.

Here is the sample of *VSTS task* in GitHub for you reference: [vsts-tasks/Tasks/](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks)

Answer (score 1):

Your understand is correct. The build tasks are stored in separate folders after upload them to VSTS/TFS. So you must place all the required files in the build task folder when you packing it. If you want to share the classes, you can consider to use npm package.